# Trying to pass a list of objects using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to pass a list of objects into a MVC controller method but I receive just a null object. What am I doing wrong?

List that I am trying to pass:

```
coordList = [{"page":1,"xStart":118,"xEnd":481,"yStart":139,"yEnd":422},{"page":2,"xStart":74,"xEnd":379,"yStart":37,"yEnd":387},{"page":3,"xStart":128,"xEnd":349,"yStart":19,"yEnd":326}]
```

Ajax call:

```
 var request = $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: Router.action("Api", "GetTable"),
                   dataType: 'json',
                   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                   data: JSON.stringify({ 'coords': coordList }),
               });
```

Controller method:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetTable(List<PageCoordModel> coords)
  {
         .....
  }
```

PageCoordModel:

```
public class PageCoordModel
{
    public String page { get; set; }

    public int xStart { get; set; }

    public int xEnd { get; set; }

    public int yStart { get; set; }

    public int yEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: You cannot use `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` with a GET (a GET has no body - the data is sent as a query string). You need to make a POST (or name you properties with collection indexers)

Comment: Also your variable name is `coordsList` and you are using `coordList` in your ajax call, which should give you a script error like **coordList is not defined**.

Comment: Decorate your action method with `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpGet]`. Change the type in ajax call to `type: 'POST'` and fix your typos in your variable name it will work

Comment: When I wrote the question, I did not copy the name of the list and that's why the typo had occurred. Thanks for the help, I changed the ajax type and it worked.